# How do I hibernate my computer?

Tags: hibernate

I tried the command

```
sudo s2disk
```

but the OS said command not found so I went and installed

```
sudo apt-get install uswsusp
```

now the command worked, and the computer did hibernate, but it failed to resume.

I also installed

```
gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
```

hoping that hibernate would show up in the menu, but it didn't. (I did press the Alt key)

Comment: there should ba button called hibernate

Comment: do you have a swap partition?

Comment: OP did you find an answer? if yes, please consider posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case you have any graphics card in your system make sure your currently installed driver has no hibernate/suspend issues.

I had similar issue of machine failing to resume, installing the latest graphics driver (catalyst 11.12 in my case) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

when you hold key ALT, and click power, you will see poweroff transe to hibernate, enjoy